# Python __init__ without executing a variable

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to init a variable in a class. This variable is dependent of other variables that I init in the same class too. Here is an example.

```
Class class():
    def __init__()
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
        self.sum = self.a + self.b

    def change_a_and_b()
       self.a = input("a = ")
       self.b = input("b = ")

    def print_sum()
        print(self.sum)
```

This is a simplified example. In my program self.sum is a complicated calculation which I want to use like a "shortcut" so I don't need to write it a lot of times. The problem is I input the variables after the **init** function. I just don't want to execute `self.sum = self.a + self.b` when I run `__init__`. I think there is `a do_thing` parameter, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Why don't you set `sum` in `change_a_and_b`?

Comment: Because it is ment to be a calculation I use in different function for the same class

Comment: So? You will always have to use it *after* you call `change_a_and_b`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `sum` a property:

```
class my_class():
    def __init__(self)
        self.a = None
        self.b = None

    @property
    def sum(self):
        return self.a + self.b

    def change_a_and_b(self)
       self.a = input("a = ")
       self.b = input("b = ")

    def print_sum(self)
        print(self.sum)
```

Comment: Can I still access it like a normal self.variable ?

Comment: Yup, exactly like you see in the example (try it out). That's the point of a property, it's a kind of syntactic sugar for treating a function like a variable.

Comment: Do I still access it with self.sum or not ?

Comment: Yes, you do. `self.sum`, and *not* `self.sum()`.